# Imagem com scroll na vertical e altura 100%

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<div class="bg">
    <img src="view/img/planta-supermercado.png" id="bg">
    <div class="bg-scroll" id="bg-scroll">
        <img src="view/img/planta-supermercado.png" id="bg-mobile">
    </div>
</div>
```

quando abrir a página pelo mobile, ele carrega a div com o id `bg-scroll`

o que eu preciso é que a imagem fique 100% na altura e proporcional na largura(a largura é maior que a altura)... e para isso acontecer eu devo criar um scroll horizontal apenas na imagem(ou na div `bg-scroll`) para que o usuário consiga ver toda a imagem.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara eu não entendi direito o que vc quer. *Mas acredito que seja algo como isso. Mas se não for exatamente isso é só dar um toque.*

**OBS:** Aqui eu usei valores pequenos para simular que vc está em uma tele de celular etc. O que eu fiz foi colocar um `overflow:auto` na div pai basicamente.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.bg {
    width: 20vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    background-color: #f00;
}
    
.bg img {
    display:block;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
    <!-- <img src="view/img/planta-supermercado.png" id="bg"> -->
    <div class="bg-scroll" id="bg-scroll">
        <img src="http://placecage.com/300/100" id="bg-mobile">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eu tinha colocado errado na publicação, é exatamente isso que preciso, mas a barra é na horizontal, desculpe.

Comment: Agora o scroll na horizontal está certo, porém quero que a imagem fique 100% de altura, e a largura fique do tamanho necessário para não perder a proporção

Comment: como a imagem é mais larga, a barra iria aparecer dessa forma que você fez, apenas na horizontal

Comment: @OtavioSouzaRocha dei uma editada novamente, olha ai se agora ficou certo

Comment: Isso mesmo, mais uma vez, obrigado!!!

Comment: @OtavioSouzaRocha tmj jovem []´s

Answer (score 1):

```
.bg {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

Se estiver usando viewport facilita seu trabalho.
A unidade vh basicamente verifica "quantos % da tela" seu elemento ocupará

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro o css para sua imagem:

```
#bg-mobile{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Agora a div:

```
#bg{
  position: relative;

}
```

Com este css sua div ficará em bg

Comment: Eu preciso que a imagem fique 100% height e o width fique proporcional, maior que a tela, e para que o usuário consiga vizualizar toda a imagem, um scroll vertical apareceria apenas na div com a imagem

Comment: dessa forma que você fez, a imagem fica 100% largura, mas na altura ela fica pequena

Comment: Na forma como especificou no primeiro comentário, da a entender que vc quer que ele fique proporcional na largura, assim sendo vai gerar um scroll horizontal, um dos dois requisitos nao parece estar certo, ou ele vai ter scroll vertical ficando com largura 100% e altura proporcional ou ele vai ter scroll horizontal, ficando 100% de altura e largura maior q a tela.